# how to prevent jerk in chat application - vb.net

Tags: .net, chat

there is jerking in text in my chat application (particularly in IE)   as i have set timer for refresh the content for each one second how to prevent this

Comment: I have no idea what this is trying to ask, but the wording is awesome.

Comment: Needs more jerking in chat rooms.

Answer (score 1):

if using ajax, rather than "replacing" the content in the div, "append" to it

eg. with jquery, rather than

```
$('#convo').html('<p>Msg1</p><p>Msg2</p><p>Msg3</p>');
```

do

```
$('#convo').append('<p>Msg1</p>');
$('#convo').append('<p>Msg2</p>');
$('#convo').append('<p>Msg3</p>');
```